# How to use/import "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision"?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use `using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision;` & `using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.Contract;` but I am not able to install `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision` as a NuGet Package in my Visual Studio Project.

How can I use both of them in my project? I am new to Xamarin and Visual Studio and not able to find a solution by myself.

Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 2):

As regards [`Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK`](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK), it's a deprecated project by Microsoft. I recommanded that you need to move to Azure Cognitive Service to learn about [`Computer Vision API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) based on cloud, then to use in your Xamarin project.

There is an offical sample code [`Cognitive Services Vision C# SDK quickstart samples`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/cognitive-services-vision-csharp-sdk-quickstarts/) which you can refer to.